# sed - Replace new line characters not followed by 5-digit number

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a csv file with some (dirty) DB schema.

example:

```
10391,0,3,4,12,44 --ok
10391,0,3,4,      --not ok
12,44             --not ok
10391,0,3,4,12,44 --ok
```

I want to write sed script to replace new line characters (not followed by 5-digit number) with spaces.

Wrote this one, but not works correctly for me:

```
sed 's/\n\([0-9]{1,4}\)/ \1/g'
```

running on this sample

```
11111 sss
22222 aaa
3333 aaa
333 sss
22 sss
1 sss
```

should produce

```
11111 sss
22222 aaa 3333 aaa 333 sss 22 sss 1 sss
```

thanks to anyone who will be able to help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Or use a Perl One-Liner

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n(?!\d{5}\b)/ /g' yourfile
```

**Explanation**

- `\n` matches the newline
- `(?!\d{5}\b)` asserts that what follows is not five digits and a word boundary
- we insert a space

Comment: I don't understand the `\b` ? Why not simply `(?!\d{5})` ? There is obviously a reason -- just can't make my mind on it...

Comment: The `\b` is an assumption I made on your needs after looking at your input—you can take it out if that assumption is off. From your input, it looks like the lines you want to "protect" start with five digits broken from the rest of the line, as in `12345 foo`. The `\b` ensures we protect these lines but not lines such as `12345_foo` or `1234567 foo` or `12345foo`. If you also want to "protect" these kinds of lines, you can take out the `\b`. Let me know if this is unclear. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -v ORS= 'NR > 1 { printf /^[0-9]{5} / ? "\n" : " " } 1
    END { if (NR) printf "\n" }' file
```

Output:

```
11111 sss
22222 aaa 3333 aaa 333 sss 22 sss 1 sss
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{printf "%s%s" ,(NR>1&&$0~/^[0-9]{5} /?"\n":" "),$0}END{print ""}'
```

should work for your example:

```
kent$  echo "11111 sss
22222 aaa
3333 aaa
333 sss
22 sss
1 sss"|awk '{printf "%s%s" ,(NR>1&&$0~/^[0-9]{5} /?"\n":" "),$0}END{print ""}'
11111 sss
22222 aaa 3333 aaa 333 sss 22 sss 1 sss
```